# Excel File printing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, printing

I create a crystalReport and export it to Excel in server machine.
Now in background only I need to print the file.
Is it possible to print the content directly to the client printer without opening the file

please Help

Comment: What OS is this? Yes, this is possible depending on the network. I mean, will you have a VPN open during this time?

Answer (score 1):

That will be difficult. 
Except if the client printer is in the same network and you know which client is attached to which printer. E.g. this could be done in a Intranet.

Comment: Can you not just issue the print command and Windows will use the default printer?

Comment: Right, but he want's to print it from the server on the users printer. It's not from the client machine.

Comment: Its client server application in internet not in intranet! so how to print the excel file to the client printer?

Comment: You can't with a Web Application. The client has to print it manually. Imagine if I could just start to print stuff on anybody's printer :-)